# Symfony 5 autowire injection into a reusable bundle

Tags: symfony5

I am trying to inject the RequestStack into my reusable bundle in Symfony 5:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
    class ICatcherSeo extends Bundle
    {    
        function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
            $RequestStack = $requestStack;
        }
```

My services.yaml:

```
App\ICatcher\Seo\:
    resource: '../bundles/ICatcher/Seo/*'
    autowire: true
```

This throws an error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\ICatcher\Seo\ICatcherSeo::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\SERVER-7_2\htdocs\compasswebdesign\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait.php on line 74 and exactly 1 expected
```

Comment: Why do you need this in the bundle class ? That's not a normal behaviour

Comment: So that I can grab the current route info, do things based on the route within the re-usable Bundle, then use the result in my projects? What would be normal behavior?

Comment: Well depends on what you want to do, but most likely to put your code in controllers, listeners, services, etc...

Comment: Got it - it works if I inject it into Bundle's service and then inject the service into project's controller. Could you please make an answer of what you said and I will mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to inject anything into the bundle since the code of your bundle shouldn't be there (only some specific action and configuration).

The code of your bundle, just like the code of a project should be in controllers, listeners, services, depending on what is your goal.